# How to save the values of FormArray Fields on Submit?

Tags: angular, formarray

I have 5 fields MeetingId, TimeId, Date, Start, End and I want Date Start and End as FormArray Fields.I have correct Add and Delete Function. Please someone help me on how to save it.

I have tried with Form Groups. It worked. But Form Arrays is not working

```
<form [formGroup]="scheduleForm" class="scheduleForm">
  <ol>
    <li formArrayName="scheduleFormArray"
        *ngFor="let item of scheduleForm.get('scheduleFormArray').controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="dateField">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [min]="minDate" placeholder="Datum" formControlName="date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="from">
        <input matInput placeholder="von" formControlName="start">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="to">
        <input matInput placeholder="bis" formControlName="end">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-icon class="cancel" (click)="deleteScheduleColumn(i)">delete</mat-icon>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <mat-icon (click)="addItems()" class="addInput">add_circle</mat-icon>
  <button mat-button class="next" (click)="saveSchedule()">Weiter</button>
</form>
```

```
private scheduleFormArray: FormArray;
private scheduleForm: FormGroup;
schedule: TimePeriod[] = [];
public newSchedule: TimePeriod = new TimePeriod(0, null, null, null, null);

public saveSchedule() {
    if (this.scheduleForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.newSchedule.tID = this.scheduleForm.value.tID;
      this.newSchedule.date = this.scheduleForm.value.date;
      this.newSchedule.start = this.scheduleForm.value.start;
      this.newSchedule.end = this.scheduleForm.value.end;
     this.newSchedule.mID = this.scheduleForm.value.mID;
      this.timePeriodService.addSchedule(this.newSchedule).subscribe(
        (t: TimePeriod) => {
          let newTimePeriod = this.schedule;
          newTimePeriod.push(t);
          this.schedule = [...newTimePeriod];
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

My addItems() and deleteScheduleColumn() methods work. Please help me with the saveSchedule() method.

Comment: Done. But my SaveSchedule method is wrong. Do you know a solution for it??

Comment: Please see this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so58412218-formarray-schedule)

Comment: Now you've fixed the form array your question "Please help me with the saveSchedule() " is unanswerable. You post doesn't include what's wrong or the relevant code.

Comment: That#s great. But I already have a model both in front End and Backend and I should go according to that.         export class TimePeriod {
  constructor(
    public mID: number = 0,
    public tID: number = 0,
    public date: Moment,
    public start: string = '',
    public end: string = '',
  ) {}
} .     That#s the reason, I am not able to patch this up. I cannot use an interface like you have mentioned

Comment: @Niranjana please show the error what you are getting, and what is you have implemented in `timePeriodService.addSchedule() method` try by changing `date: Moment` to `date: Date` or `date: string`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Update your **saveSchedule** method like that :

```
public saveSchedule() {
    if (this.scheduleForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.newSchedule.tID = this.scheduleForm.controls['tID'].value;
      this.newSchedule.date = this.scheduleForm.controls['date'].value;
      this.newSchedule.start = this.scheduleForm.controls['start'].value;
      this.newSchedule.end = this.scheduleForm.controls['end'].value;
     this.newSchedule.mID = this.scheduleForm.controls['mID'].value;
      this.timePeriodService.addSchedule(this.newSchedule).subscribe(
        (t: TimePeriod) => {
          let newTimePeriod = this.schedule;
          newTimePeriod.push(t);
          this.schedule = [...newTimePeriod];
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at TryComponent.saveSchedule (try.component.ts:77)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TryComponent.html:56)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43992)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45631)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45246)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29803)
    at core.js:42924
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)

Comment: I get an error mentioned above. it does not allow the word controls and value present in this line  -  this.newSchedule.tID = this.scheduleForm.controls['tID'].value;

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you all. I have made the below changes and it is now working.

public saveSchedule() {
     if (this.scheduleForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.scheduleFormArray.value.forEach(s => {
        this.newSchedule = new TimePeriod(s.tID, s.date, s.start, s.end, s.mID);
        this.timePeriodService.addSchedule(this.newSchedule).subscribe(
          (t: TimePeriod) => {
            let newTimePeriod = this.schedule;
            newTimePeriod.push(t);
            this.schedule = [...newTimePeriod];
          }
        );
      });
    }
  }
```